# Custom table data on admin panel in umbraco

Tags: c#, database, datasource, umbraco

I want to know **how we can get the data for the custom table** from the database and display it on the **Umbraco 11 admin panel**.

- In Umbraco, we have a form. When we create a form, entries are generated.
  [ https://prnt.sc/rB_SH2E8YEmc ], and I want the exact same entries for my custom table.
- I try to create the controllers and create a view but I have a problem with the controller and a model error in the view.
- I want to find out how to get data from my custom table and list all this data on the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to interfere with Umbraco Forms after a new item has been submitted:

1. create an event which you can [trigger after the save](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-forms/developer/extending/adding-an-event-handler)
2. create a [custom workflow](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-forms/developer/extending/adding-a-workflowtype) which can be configured by the editor in the cms

To [store data in the custom table you can inject a scope](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/extending/database#working-with-data-in-custom-database-tables) and add data to the table or if you use [newer umbraco versions, you can use EntityFramework core](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/tutorials/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core)

To create and display data in the backend you can do that in different ways. One way would be to [create a custom dashboard](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/tutorials/creating-a-custom-dashboard).

Your remark with controllers and views is a little too vague. As this is a Q&A website, I suggest you first try the [Umbraco Forum](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/) or [Umbraco Discord](https://community.umbraco.com/get-involved/community-discord-server/). Or create a new elaborate question here on StackOverflow explaining exactly what you are trying to do, include some code, error messages, ...