# Data source file in Umbraco

Tags: c#, database, datasource, umbraco

- How we **create the data-Source file** which is located in the form section and how to **connect data-source files with a custom table**.

I created one data-Source file in which they ask for the connection string and table name. After saving that file we have one option to create a form from that file but after creating that I render macro at my content page but then it gives me the SQL error.

So, my main question is how can I create data-Source files and how to use that files in my content page. I need a reference.

Comment: This is similar to your previous question.  Best way is to first query the database and put results into a datatable.  Then add/modify values in the DataTable.  Finally save the updated datatable back to the database.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom table data on admin panel in umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76951624/custom-table-data-on-admin-panel-in-umbraco)